# Error with gunicorn server start

Tags: python, server, wsgi, gunicorn

On an external server, I tried to run the command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 jeremiesblog.wsgi:application
```

I got this error:

```
[2017-01-29 15:08:02 +0000] [19640] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2017-01-29 15:08:02 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2017-01-29 15:08:02 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-01-29 15:08:03 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2017-01-29 15:08:03 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-01-29 15:08:04 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2017-01-29 15:08:04 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-01-29 15:08:05 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2017-01-29 15:08:05 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-01-29 15:08:06 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
[2017-01-29 15:08:06 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-01-29 15:08:07 +0000] [19640] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message:

> Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000)

Indicates the port is in use.  You need to find whoever is currently using the port and turn them off.  If you can `sudo`, you can use `netstat` to find who is already using the port:

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :80
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  125004/gunicorn
```

In the example above it is `guincorn` with a pid of `125004`.

([Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106562/208146))

Answer (score 18):

I got the same error but all I do is kill my port 8000 from this command.

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Now you can run the command

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 jeremiesblog.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
pgrep gunicorn
```

It will return you the pid, something like this:

```
23716
23718
```

Now kill any one of them (or all) using:

```
kill 23716
```

You can recheck using `pgrep gunicorn` if it's still running.